# Dynamic sql stored procedure update query issue?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I've written the below code to set filepath column in my table as `'F:\DataMigration\Wise\DELTA_20121008\Attachments\SR\SR_1.txt'`

```
where SR_1 is file_name column
      .txt is file_ext column from my table.
```

but after executing following procedure, I'm getting filepath column in table as

```
'F:\DataMigration\Wise\DELTA_20121008\Attachments\file_name.file_ext'
```

means It's treating column names as string, how i can make it as column so it will
use values in that column.

```
alter procedure [dbo].[WISEMissingAttachmentReportGenerator]
(
@tablename varchar(255), @pathonlocal nvarchar(255)
)
as
begin
--step 1
exec dbo.proc_alter_table @tablename
--step 2
EXEC ('update '+ @tablename +
' set filepath = '''+ @pathonlocal + ' file_name'+'.'+'file_ext''')
EXEC('Select * from '+@tablename)
end

exec [dbo].[WISEMissingAttachmentReportGenerator] [WISE.Non_VP_Service_Request_Attachments_File_Check_Analysis],
N'F:\DataMigration\Wise\DELTA_20121008\Attachments\SR\'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try;

```
EXEC('UPDATE '+ @tablename +
' SET filepath = '''+ @pathonlocal + ''' + file_name + '''+'.'+''' + file_ext')
```

Equal as;

```
UPDATE [YourTable] SET filepath = 'YourPath' + file_name + '.' + file_ext
```

Comment: Thanks man, I always get confused while using single quotes with Dynamic sql, can you tell me why three continuous single quotes before @pathonlocal variable.

Comment: coz `@pathonlocal` is a `string` which has just the value. So you need it enclosed with `'your_string'`. This is valid for any string type variable. Out of 3 `'''` quotation marks, `'` for ending `'SET filepath = '` and `from other 2 one as **escape character** to the other.`

Comment: Concatenation of a dot is not needed, it can just be included in a string, instead of `'''+'.'+'''` in `file_name + '''+'.'+''' + file_ext` it can just be `file_name + ''.'' + file_ext`, it will give a correct output, it's more simple this way and it saves you one concatenation operation.

Comment: @IvanG, Yes true, I left it for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your statement to this:

```
EXEC ('update '+ @tablename +
' set filepath = '''+ @pathonlocal + ''' + file_name + ''.'' + file_ext')
```

Comment: To write single quotes inside literal string you have to double them, so you get subsequent 3 single quotes when the inner quotes are closed in front of the outer closing quote. Try this: `SELECT  'What''s your name? My name is ''Joe''...'`, If there weren't for the `...` on the end it would look as if there are 3 subsequent single quotes at the end - `SELECT  'What''s your name? My name is ''Joe'''`

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @tblnm varchar(20) = 'test'
declare @upda varchar(20) = 'update '
declare @set varchar(25) = ' set'
declare @id varchar(25) = ' id'
declare @cmd varchar(1000)

set @cmd = @upda + @tblnm + @set + @id + '=7'
exec(@cmd)

SAMPLE SQL UPDATE QUERY - FOR BUILDING TABLENAME DYNAMICALLY  
EXECUTED GUYS - THIS IS CALL JUGAAAAAAAAAD [NO NEED TO GET INTO ''' STUFF]
```