# Use string from form as parameter in stored procedure (SQL Server)

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlsrv

I've been trying to follow the example from this question ([Insert Stored Procedure and other variables into a temp table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44204631/insert-stored-procedure-and-other-variables-into-a-temp-table)) and this one ([Dynamic sql stored procedure update query issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13740678/dynamic-sql-stored-procedure-update-query-issue)) to get this working but no joy as yet. I've been dipping my toe into more complex SQL queries (still learning) and would love some advice/guidance on this one.

I am trying to take a string from a form submitted on a webpage (PHP) to go into a where clause for an update query in a stored procedure. The end goal is to alter all the provided reference numbers to a statusrefno of 4 (which would mark them as closed rental products)

Here is the stored procedure in full

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestingPPMRemovals]
    @EditedBy varchar (25),
    @PPMsList varchar (max)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    CREATE table #tempPPMs (PPMs varchar(max))
    INSERT INTO #tempPPMs (PPMs) VALUES (@PPMsList)

    INSERT INTO PPMsEdit_AuditTrail (EditedBy, EditDate, PPMsEdited) 
    VALUES (@EditedBy, getdate(), @PPMsList)

    UPDATE jobs 
    SET StatusRefNo = 4, EditUserRefNo = 1114 
    WHERE WebReference IN (SELECT * FROM #tempPPMs) 

END
```

The list of these web references would look something like this in a query

```
UPDATE jobs 
SET StatusRefNo = 4, EditUserRefNo = 1114 
WHERE WebReference IN ('PPM-372046', 'PPM-372053', 'PPM-372072', 'PPM-372076', 'PPM-372077', 'PPM-372078')
```

I understand that the 'IN' is not compatible with a stored procedure and while the risk of SQL injection is very low because this webpage will only be accessible locally, I would like to negate that risk as much as possible.

The alternative way I tried to do this query did not work either which is here -

```
INSERT INTO PPMsEdit_AuditTrail (EditedBy, EditDate, PPMsEdited) 
VALUES (@EditedBy, getdate(), @PPMsList)

UPDATE jobs 
SET StatusRefNo = 4, EditUserRefNo = 1114 
WHERE WebReference IN (
   SELECT Top 1 PPMsEdited 
   FROM PPMsEdit_AuditTrail 
   ORDER BY EditDate desc
)
```

Here is the relevant section from my PHP in case it is needed for context -

```
$sqlsrv = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo) or die(sqlsrv_error($sqlsrv));
$update = false;
$EditedBy = '';
$PPMsList = '';
$tsql = 'exec TestingPPMRemovals ?, ?';


if (isset($_POST['update'])){
    $PPMsList = $_POST['PPMsList'];
    $EditedBy = $_POST['EditedBy'];    
    
    $params = array($PPMsList, $EditedBy);
    $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql, $params);
    if ($result === false) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
        $response = array('response'=>'notok', 'data'=>'loyo');
        $serverresponse = json_encode($response);
    } else {
        $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC);
        $response = array('response'=>'ok', 'data'=>$row[0]);
        $serverresponse = json_encode($response);
    }
    sqlsrv_free_stmt($result);
} else {
    $response = array('response'=>'notok', 'flag'=>$flag, 'data'=>'cc');
    $serverresponse = json_encode($response);
}

echo ($serverresponse);
    
    $_SESSION['message'] = "This information has been succesfully updated";
    $_SESSION['msg_returndate'] = "info";
    
    header("location: ../success.php");
```

I had based that PHP code on a lesson from Dani Krossing's PHP Youtube tutorials (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5wGDu-aigZs&list=PL0eyrZgxdwhwBToawjm9faF1ixePexft-&index=33)

Any advice or resources to help me get this working would be great. I have spent a good chunk of time looking for another post that would help but haven't found any.

Thanks

Comment: You make assumptions that are incorrect. Start by reading Erland's discussion on [arrays and lists](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html). Bookmark his site - lots of useful information

Comment: Unfortunately it appears PHP does not suppport Table Valued Parameters, which is what you really need. I would say hack around it with XML or JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to take a string from a form submitted on a webpage (PHP) to go into a where clause for an update query in a stored procedure.

For this you need a splitter (AKA tokenizer). If you are using SQL 2016+ you have [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). For earlier versions you can grab [this](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2). With `@WebReferenceNumbers` as the "submitted string" your SQL would look like this:

```
DECLARE @WebReferenceNumbers VARCHAR(8000) =
  'PPM-372046,PPM-372053,PPM-372072,PPM-372076,PPM-372077,PPM-372078'

-- SELECT | UPDATE | WHATEVER WHERE... IN
SELECT s.[value]
FROM   STRING_SPLIT(@WebReferenceNumbers,',') AS s;
```

There may be a little cleanup such as whitespace trimming required based on what the string looks like but this is a simple task.

Comment: Thank you @Alan-Burstein for your help! Greatly appreciated